# Add special character in inline expression

Tags: math-mode, characters

I am tring to write this line using latex (on overleaf edit): modalité_classe1 , where classe1 appears as the index of modalité . So I tried this command:

```
$modalité_{classe1}$
```

It seems to work, however in my output the `é` got removed. To me , it is a special character, but i didn't find how to handle it within a `$...$` inline expression.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: something like `$\text{modalité}_{\text{classe1}}$` (needs `amsmath`)?

Answer (score 1):

Updated as per @DavidCarlisle's comment and removed the math inline.

With `lmodern` with `fontenc` (with `T1`), you can achieve by using `\'`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
      modalit\'e\textsubscript{classe1}
\end{document}
```

to get this output:

[image: Screenshot]

But I hope this helps.

Comment: No please don't suggest doing this, you should not use math italic for multi-letter words so `$modalite_{classe1}$` is already wrong even though it gives no error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle May I know how else to achieve this? Since, it did not bump me with errors I thought it was okay :D.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer:

```
$modalit\textrm{é}_{classe1}$
```

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Your solution is not quite good on a typographic point of view. `modalit` would be math-styled `\textrm{é}` woud be  roman style. Just a quick tip: If you only need this to have `classe1` as a subscript, you can use `modalité\textsubscript{classe1}` instead?

Comment: Ye sure ! yours is also a solution to the same issue. :) I did use this 
 expression $\textrm{modalité}_{classe1}$